# Prevent a Save of Activesheet from saving a link to a module

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have an Excel / VBA question. I've come across a circumstance where VBA is being used to save a large number of activesheets as individual workbooks. Itself not an issue. However in the workbook they are being saved from there is a module that needs to be in each of the new individual files. The save method is saving a link to the module and not the module itself.

I'm looking for method of saving the activesheets as workbooks and forcing the module to be included in each of the new files. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to show code references for this but any experience someone may have with this type of issue would be appreciated.

All the files are being save as type .xlsm and also save the format is set to Macro Enabled Workbook

The Excel Version is 2013

Comment: There are three approaches you can take to this: use vba to add the module in to the new workbook, or, get the workbook that has the module to save itself as the destination file (thereby copying the macro) and work from there, or, save the macro in a blank workbook, which the workbook executing the save opens, does a save as, and then adds in the worksheets. Please update if you have code-specific questions.

Comment: Save the whole workbook as NewWorkbookName and delete all but target sheet?